# R use of lapply() to populate and name one column in list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, names

After searching for some time, I cannot find a smooth R-esque solution.

I have a list of vectors that I want to convert to dataframes and add a column with the names of the vectors. I cant do this with cbind() and melt() to a single dataframe b/c there are vectors with different number of rows.

Basic example would be:

```
list<-list(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6,7))
var<-"group"
```

What I have come up with and works is:

```
list<-lapply(list, function(x) data.frame(num=x,grp=""))

for (j in 1:length(list)){
  list[[j]][,2]<-names(list[j])
  names(list[[j]])[2]<-var
}
```

But I am trying to better use lapply() and have cleaner coding practices. Right now I rely so heavily on for and if statements, which a lot of the base functions do already and much more efficiently than I can code at this point.

The psuedo code I would like is something like:

```
list<-lapply(list, function(x) data.frame(num=x,get(var)=names(x))
```

Is there a clean way to get this done?

Second closely related question, if I already have a list of dataframes, why is it so hard to reassign column values and names using lapply()?

So using something like:

```
list<-list(a=data.frame(num=c(1,2,3),grp=""),b=data.frame(num=c(4,5,6,7),grp=""))
var<-"group"

#pseudo code
list<-lapply(list, function(x) x[,2]<-names(x)) #populate second col with name of df[x]
list<-lapply(list, function(x) names[[x]][2]<-var) #set 2nd col name to 'var'
```

The first line of pseudo code throws an error about matching row lengths. Why does lapply() not just loop over and repeat names(x) like the same function on a single dataframe does in a for loop?

For the second line, as I understand it I can use setNames() to reassign all the column names, but how do I make this work for just one of the col names?

Many thanks for any ideas or pointing to other threads that cover this and helping me understand the behavior of lapply() in this context.

Comment: Be careful naming your objects after built-in functions and objects, such as `list`.

Comment: @coffeinjunky sure, thanks. just trying to make the example. ls would been better though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A full R base approach without using loops

```
> l<-list(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6,7))
> data.frame(grp=rep(names(l), lengths(l)), num=unlist(l), row.names = NULL)
  grp num
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   b   4
5   b   5
6   b   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Related to your first/main question you can use the function `enframe` from package `tibble` for this purpose

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

l<-list(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6,7))

l %>% 
  enframe(name = "group", value="value") %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  group_split(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
mylist <- list(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6,7))
bind_rows(lapply(names(mylist), function(x) tibble(grp = x, num = mylist[[x]])))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  grp     num
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 a         2
3 a         3
4 b         4
5 b         5
6 b         6
7 b         7
```

This is essentially a `lapply`-based solution where you iterate over the names of your list, and not the individual list elements themselves. If you prefer to do everything in base R, note that the above is equivalent to

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(mylist), function(x) data.frame(grp = x, num = mylist[[x]], stringsAsFactors = F)))
```

Having said that, `tibble`s as modern implementation of data.frames are preferred, as is `bind_rows` over the `do.call(rbind...` construct.

As to the second question, note the following:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) str(x))
 num [1:3] 1 2 3
 num [1:4] 4 5 6 7
....
lapply(mylist, function(x) names(x))
$a
NULL
$b
NULL
```

What you see here is that the function inside of `lapply` gets the elements of `mylist`. In this case, it get's to work with the numeric vector. This does not have any name as far as the function that is called inside `lapply` is concerned. To highlight this, consider the following:

```
names(c(1,2,3))
NULL
```

Which is the same: the vector `c(1,2,3)` does not have a name attribute.